# Docker multi stage build on Openshift

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift

I try to use multi-stage build to build a docker image on openshift.

I can build the image using following Dockerfile in Linux and Windows box, but I got error when I try to build it on openshift.

**My openshift version**

```
OpenShift Master: v3.11.0+5407964-426
Kubernetes Master:v1.11.0+d4cacc0
OpenShift Web Console:v3.11.0+ea42280
```

**Part of Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:buster as debian-odbc-driver
.
.

FROM continuumio/miniconda3 as builder
.
.
RUN conda config --set ssl_verify /etc/ca-bundle.trust.crt &&  \
    conda create --name myenv python=3.7.3 --no-default-packages && \
    conda create -n dask --clone myenv --offline &&  \
    conda env create -n "env" python=3.7.3 -f environment.yml &&\
    conda create -n dataduct --clone env --offline 

FROM php:7-apache
.
.
COPY --from=debian-odbc-driver /tmp/dremio-odbc_1.5.0.1001-2_amd64.deb /tmp
.
.
COPY --from=builder /opt/conda/ /home/root/test/
#The following command also not work....
#COPY --from=builder --chown=root:root /opt/conda/ /home/root/test/
```

Error log

`error: build error: API error (404): {"message":"Error processing tar file(exit status 1): link /conda/envs/dask/bin/clear /home/root/test/envs/dataduct/bin/clear: no such file or directory"}`

I believe the multi-stage build can work on openshift, we can successfully copy the first stage image file into the php image.

Please give some suggestion for this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a complete Containerfile so I can't reproduce your error, but have a look at this line:

COPY --from=builder /opt/conda/ /home/root/test/

You appear to be copying files from one container into a target directory (/home/root/test/) that does not already exit.

We can assume /home/root exists, so try: /home/root/test - also, since the other COPY works to copy into /tmp I would duplicate the second COPY into /tmp to isolate whether it's a problem with the source container, or the target.